# What does eq? predicate do in mit scheme interpreter?

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, lisp

I know that `(eq? obj1 obj2)` returns `#t` only if both obj1 and obj2 refer to the same object in memory.

1) `(eq? 2.6 2.6)` returns `#f` as they are floating point numbers and representation of floats are different in scheme. Could someone explain how they are represented in memory?.

2) Why do pairs and non empty strings often return `#f` even if we have not declared them before? example:  `(eq? (cons 1 2) (cons 1 2))` , while comparing same numbers with `eq?` gives same results as of `equal?` predicate.

For example, `(define x 3) (define y 3) (eq? x y)` returns `#t`.

I also understand that `(eq? '() '())` returns `#t` as there is only a single representation of null list in memory and that is a pointer to 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To understand this you really need to know something about how Lisps typically represent objects.  The following is not specific to MIT Scheme and may not even be correct for it (or any specific implementation) but is meant to give you some idea of what the considerations are in general.  There are other possible representations than the one sketched below, but they all have similar tradeoffs.

### Object representation

First of all, the system needs to know two things about any object:

- what sort of thing it is -- its type;
- what its value is -- some pattern of bits which represents the object.

The pattern of bits only makes sense in the context of the type, of course.

There are a lot of types, and in many Lisp dialects you can make new types, so it's not going to work to say 'there can only be these six sorts of thing' for instance.  But some types are more important than others (I was going to say 'some types are more equal than others'): you probably want smallish integers to be pretty efficient for instance.

Well, in most cases you are going to end up with some kind of pointer to the actual data of the object.  But there's now a clever trick you can do: most (all?) modern machines are byte-addressed -- memory addresses work at the granularity 8 bits.  But  if you only want to point at larger objects, you have spare bits in your pointer.  So if you're on a 64-bit machine and you want to point only at things on 64-bit boundaries, the low 3 bits of your pointers are never used, and if you only want to point at 128-bit boundaries you have 4 spare bits.

So you can do a devious trick: in a single 64-bit word you can pack a pointer and, in the few bits at the botton of the pointer that you don't need, a tag which can encode the few most important types.

And you can do even better than this: for some small objects you can pack the object *itself* where the pointer goes.  The canonical case of this is small integers -- the things Lisps have historically called fixnums.  So in your word you now have a pattern of tag bits which says 'this is a fixnum' and the actual bits of the fixnum, shifted right to make room for the tag.  (In practice you generally have two tags for 'even fixnum' and 'odd fixnum' which let you do a devious trick to make fixnums a bit bigger which I'll leave you to work out).  Lisps would traditionally also do this for `NIL` / `()` which might traditionally be a special 'nil' tag with the rest of the word being zeros.  This might make less sense for Scheme, I am not sure.

But you can't do this in general: most objects have to be stored with a pointer, and in the most general case the tag bits in the word will say 'it's something else', and the pointer will point to some object which has both the type of the thing and the value of it, and will be several words long.

Objects which are stored immediately like smallish integers are often called 'unboxed', while general pointer-based objects are called 'boxed'.

### What `eq?` does

So, what does `eq?` do?  Simple: it tells you if the two words are the same pattern of bits: if both the tag and the pointer/immediate value are the same bits.  This is extremely fast (a single instruction) but also extremely primitive.

For immediate types such as fixnums it will tell you if the two objects have the same value.  For pointer types it will tell you if two objects are identical: if two pointers point to the same address (and have the same tag bits, although it would be very odd if they did not).  What it *won't* do is tell you if two pointer types represent the same value even though they are different pointers.

### Interning: a trick

One trick you can do for boxed types is to *intern* them: every time you are about to make a new one, you have a look to see if you have made an equivalent one before and, if you have, you simply return a pointer to the same object.  This means that `eq?` will return true for any two equivalent interned objects, because they are in fact the same object.  It only really makes sense to intern objects if there will only ever be relatively small numbers of them, if they are either immutable or effectively immutable, or if you intentionally *want* this interning behaviour.

### Floating-point numbers

Floats are either 32 or 64 bits.  So on a 64-bit system you could represent a 32-bit single float immediately: you'd have some tag bits and a bunch of zeros in half the word and the bits of the float in the other half.  But you can never do this for double floats.  Even for single floats you would need to have a special 'float' tag, and tags are an extremely scarce resource -- there are perhaps only 8 of them.  (Also, of course, most Lisps were 32-bit until living memory, and a 32-bit Lisp can't even store a single float immediately.)

So, generally, both single and double floats are boxed.  It does not make sense to intern floats since you can generate huge numbers of them: a billion a second or something and they are generally not the same.

So `eq?` will usually return false on two floats, even if they are numerically the same.  However you can't really rely on it: what should something like this do?

```
(define (x f)
  (let ([g f])
    (eq? g f)))
(x 1.0)
```

It probably returns `#t` but I am not sure it has to do so.  I am fairly sure that the equivalent in CL is explicitly not defined, for instance: the implementation is allowed to copy the float.

Finally, floating-point calculations are often places where people care a lot about performance, and boxed floats hurt performance quite a lot.  So implementations very often, with suitable type declarations, can compile code which treats floats as immediate, unboxed (and untagged), objects for performance.  `eq?` would then probably return true for numerically equal floats.  But the answer is that, if you want to do numerical comparisons, use `=`: that's what it's for.

### Small integers

See the discussion above: `eq?` generally works for smallish integers, because they are stored immediately.  But it doesn't work for *all* integers:

```
> (eq? 1 1)
#t
> (eq? (expt 2 20) (expt 2 20))
#t
> (eq? (expt 2 64) (expt 2 64))
#f
> (eq? (expt 2 62) (expt 2 62))
#f
> (eq? (expt 2 61) (expt 2 61))
#t
> (eq? (- (expt 2 62) 1) (- (expt 2 62) 1))
#t
```

So for this implementation (Racket) you can see the transition between unboxed and boxed integers happening here.

But there is no requirement on an implementation as far as I am aware to store *any* integers immediately.  Again: use `=`, it's what it's for.

### Conses

Conses are always boxed and only compare `eq?` if they are the same cons.  In particular, it is the job of `cons` to create new conses, so `(eq? (cons '() '()) (cons '() '())` will never be true.

### Symbols

Symbols are the canonical interned type: `(eq 'x 'x)` is true, because it is the job of symbols for it to be true: when a symbol is read it is interned, and reading other symbols with the same name will (except in weird circumstances) return the same identical object.

I don't know enough about symbols in Scheme, but in CL you can create uninterned symbols which, although they look the same, are not.  These are useful for the names of things in macros in CL (Scheme has a cleverer approach).

### Strings

These might be interned, but probably only some of them, and you can't rely on this.  So, in Racket for instance, I think you may be able to rely on `(eq? "foo" "foo")` being true, but perhaps not, and you can probably only rely on it, if you can at all, because both strings came from the reader.  Again, you should use the right predicate.

### Special types

Things like `#t` and `()` are either not boxed or, if they are, are held uniquely (which is kind of their whole point in life), so `eq?` works on them.